# python3 request post form-data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, postman

how can i post below request in python requests library?
[image]

it works on postman but when i try to run it in python requests it shows incorrect result.
here is my code :

```
data ={'state': {'no': state_number}}
        input= {'input':data}
        headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        state_list = requests.post(url="http://myurl.com",data=input,headers=headers).json()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in postman you can generate the python code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks it works ,but the value of "no" is hardcoded(9) ..and it seems changing it with f string or format raises error because there are multiple parentheses in that string.

Comment: formating this expression would be so ugly

Comment: @Mond666 the form data is send as string , in your expression convert the dictionary to string , data ={'state': {'no': state_number}}

Comment: Do something like input= str(data)

Comment: thank you very much it works..although i had to do this with json.dumps()